# Google Analytics code for page 404 tracking in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am a beginner with wordpress and I want to ask somebody to help me. I would like to track page 404. I have 2 analytics codes. One of them is displayed on every page. The other is for displaying only on the 404 pages. I don't know where and how to put the second analytics code which is for page 404 only. I ask for an advice :)
The code is below:

```
<?php if (is_404()) { ?>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview', '/404.html?page='+document.location.pathname + document.location.search + '&from=' + document.referrer);
    </script>

<?php } else { ?>

    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
   </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, it will need to go inside of the `<head>` which will be located in the `header.php` file of your active theme:

```
<?php if(is_404()) { ?>

  Paste  404 only tracking here

<?php } else { ?>

  Paste normal tracking here

<?php } ?>
```

You'll need to add both of your tracking codes where I've labelled but that will show them on the relevant pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried but it doesn't work. I get a message for a wrong syntax.

Comment: I have tested the above and it does work, can you post up in your original answer what you are using now?

Comment: @dsokolov thats strange, I've now tested exactly what you have with errors enabled and nothing shows up? - what does the error your getting say?

Comment: Hi! I receive errors such as "syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file" and syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end of file".